# How to set a directory as hidden one?

Tags: install4j

Today I am searching for an option to set a directory as an hidden one. Therefore I created a directory beginning with a dot like `.bin`. Onmac it seems to be successfull but on windows the folder will always been displayed even if the option "Show hidden directoruies" is deactivated. Is there any option to set the hdden flag?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do the same for mac/linux and Windows. In windows you can execute this command:

```
attrib +h C:\path\to\bin\ /S
```

Comment: That's a good solution. You can execute that with a "Run executable" action. Currently install4j has no action to hide files on Windows.